# Sharepoint REST API 'search' equivalent in Graph API (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to find a way how to call Graph API with fulltext search similar to following query:

```
https://[tenant].sharepoint.com/sites/[site name/ID]/_api/search/query?queryText='([term to search]*)'
```

Basically to simulate the seach on Sharepoint site header and thus far I was not able to replicate it in the Graph API.

Note: I tried to work with Pages in /beta, but that do not allow search at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search on a specific SharePoint site by specifying `path` in `queryString`.

API looks like this

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/search/query
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "entityTypes": [
                "listItem"
            ],
            "query": {
                "queryString": "path:\"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/{site_name}\" Test"
            },
            "from": 0,
            "size": 25
        }
    ]
}
```

If you are using [Microsoft Graph .NET Client Library](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet) the code will be

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient( authProvider );

var requests = new List<SearchRequestObject>()
{
    new SearchRequestObject
    {
        EntityTypes = new List<EntityType>()
        {
            EntityType.ListItem
        },
        Query = new SearchQuery
        {
            QueryString = "path:\"https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/{site_name}\" Test"
        },
        From = 0,
        Size = 25
    }
};

await graphClient.Search
    .Query(requests)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

Resources:

[Search API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/search-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: I've tried this one, but it seems that I have only access to cetain Sites with my Application Client Id and from what I was able to find the Search is done on higer level and I always get Unauthorized. Is there way around it?